# The identitytoolkit/getProjectConfiguration doesn't return all fields

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-identity-toolkit

I tried to use the `identitytoolkit/getProjectConfig` witch should return this fields:

```
  /// Whether to allow password user sign in or sign up.
  core.bool allowPasswordUser;

  /// Browser API key, needed when making http request to Apiary.
  core.String apiKey;

  /// Authorized domains.
  core.List<core.String> authorizedDomains;

  /// Change email template.
  EmailTemplate changeEmailTemplate;
  core.String dynamicLinksDomain;

  /// Whether anonymous user is enabled.
  core.bool enableAnonymousUser;

  /// OAuth2 provider configuration.
  core.List<IdpConfig> idpConfig;

  /// Legacy reset password email template.
  EmailTemplate legacyResetPasswordTemplate;

  /// Project ID of the relying party.
  core.String projectId;

  /// Reset password email template.
  EmailTemplate resetPasswordTemplate;

  /// Whether to use email sending provided by Firebear.
  core.bool useEmailSending;

  /// Verify email template.
  EmailTemplate verifyEmailTemplate;
```

But I only get partial results, like this for example `{authorizedDomains: [localhost, flutter-sdk.firebaseapp.com], projectId: 233259864964}`
 So I went on and tried with a service account with `Owner` role. Same result. Am I missing something?

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:googleapis/identitytoolkit/v3.dart';
import 'package:googleapis_auth/auth_io.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  final ServiceAccountCredentials clientCredentials =
      ServiceAccountCredentials.fromJson(File('./configs/flutter-sdk-6fea82780c7b.json').readAsStringSync());
  final AutoRefreshingAuthClient client = await clientViaServiceAccount(
    clientCredentials,
    <String>[
      IdentitytoolkitApi.CloudPlatformScope,
      IdentitytoolkitApi.FirebaseScope,
    ],
  );

  final RelyingpartyResourceApi requester = IdentitytoolkitApi(client).relyingparty;

  print((await requester.getProjectConfig()).toJson());
}
```